# Search if class contains a specific property

Tags: c#, settings

I have a setting file in my project, that contains some `StringCollection` (one by user). Each `StringCollection` is named with a user name and contains one or more values for this user. As an example, if an user is name "User1", the settings will contain this :

```
<setting name="User1" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value>
        <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <string>mail1@test.com</string>
            <string>mail2@test.com</string>
        </ArrayOfString>
    </value>
</setting>
```

I want to test is my settings contains a certain user, i.e. I want to know if class `Properties.Settings.Default` has a property named like this user. How can I do?

If my question in unclear, I want to have something like this:

```
private bool UserExists(String user)
{
    // Test if a property in Properties.Settings.Default is named "user"
}
```

In my case, I have a field `Properties.Settings.Default.User1`. So `UserExists("User1")` must be `True` and `UserExists("User2")` must be `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load settings as [StringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) and call `Contains()` on the collection to determine if your user exist or not

Example

```
private bool UserExists(String user)
{
    // Test if a StringCollection is named "user"
    return Properties.Settings.Default.User1.Contains(user);
}
```

### EDIT

What you are trying to do is find if the settings exist or not, for that you can try something like this

```
private bool UserExist(string user)
{
   return Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Cast<SettingsProperty>().Any(prop => prop.Name == user);
}
```

Comment: I looked for this but the `Properties.Settings` is a class inherited from `global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`. The `StringCollection` is one field on this class.

Comment: But you should be able to get a `StringCollection` object on the code side through calling that property. Like `Properties.Settings.Default.User1` this should give you the `StringCollection` object.

Comment: @A.Pissicat I have edited my answer based on your question

Answer (score 0):

Or you looking for something like this?

```
private bool UserExists(String user)
{
   // Test if a StringCollection is named "user"
   return user == Properties.Settings.Default.name ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, and your clarification is confusing the issue. Your title is "Search if a string file contains a field", then you state that you want to see if your settings contain a certain user, while your clarification seems to indicate that you want the name of a collection? Since the first and last items in that list don't make much sense, I'll answer the second.

According to the [MSDN documentation for StringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) the extension method `.Contains()` does exactly what you seem to be looking for.

Here is a modified version of the documented example that lines up with your question a little more.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class SamplesStringCollection
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Creates and initializes a new StringCollection.
        StringCollection myCol = new StringCollection
        {
            "mail1@gmail.com",
            "mail2@gmail.com",
            "mail3@gmail.com",
            "mail4@gmail.com"
        };

        if (UserExists(myCol, "mail2@gmail.com"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User 2 exists!");
        }
    }

    private static bool UserExists(IList myCol, string user)
    {
        return myCol.Contains(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's more clear. I want to test if a property in my settings is named "user".

Comment: @A.Pissicat Rushi Vyas posted a working solution that matches your clarification.